# Cannot load WP8 Projects in PixPresenter Sample

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

[image]

I've installed VS2012 update 3 and WP7.8 & WP8 SDKs prior to opening the solution.

This is the entry from the activity log:

286
    2013/07/15 04:50:09.817
    Error
    VisualStudio
    SetSite failed for package [Silverlight Mobile VS Project System]
    {7D4626A3-18C3-43A4-A66C-169D1D609803}

---

80131534
    The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.DataStoreUtilities' threw an exception.

**EDIT: I also can't create a new WP8 project.**

Answer (score 0):

I get this error with Update 3.

```
  <entry>
    <record>295</record>
    <time>2013/07/15 05:18:46.163</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Silverlight Mobile VS Project System]</description>
    <guid>{7D4626A3-18C3-43A4-A66C-169D1D609803}</guid>
    <hr>80131534</hr>
    <errorinfo>The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.DataStoreUtilities' threw an exception.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

VS 2012 + Update 2 works fine. Do you really need to install Update 3?

Comment: no, not really. its just that it popped up after installation. anyway, I don't want to revert to update 2 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is what worked for me. I uninstalled Visual Studio 2012 and reinstalled it with Update 3.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling VS 2013 and then apply Update 3?

Comment: yup, I'm trying it out :)

Comment: Do you have the default values selected during install. Unchecking a component also causes this error.

Comment: yes, i did not change any of the options. I've reinstalled 2 times already